# What is the verb when someone suddenly run across the road

Tags: vocabulary

How does a native describe the action of the person when you see someone suddenly appears on the road whilst you’re driving.

“Someone ..... to the road while I was driving and I turned the wheel so hard in order not to hit”

Can I use “rush”?

Comment: "dashed across the road"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest **dash**:

> Someone **[dashed](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dash#Verb) across** the road while I was driving and I turned the wheel hard to avoid collision.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to CowperKettle's **dash across** you could use the phrase **came out of nowhere** to describe the sudden appearance of the pedestrian.

> He came out of nowhere! I had to swerve sharply so as not to hit him.

You had no warning whatsoever that he was about to cross the road. Perhaps he had stepped out from behind a parked van, or came out of an unlit area at night.